# views entity reference to point email instead of uid in contextual filter?

Tags: 7, users, views

I'm using Drupal 7 and Views. I've been trying to sort out, entity reference to enable a contextual filter to sort by email, instead of UID as currently I am doing.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you're look to contextually filter a view based on an Entity reference's (user) email, you can add a **Relationship** with the value of *Entity Reference: User*. This allows your view rows to be join with the rows in the entity that is referenced.

With the relationship added, you can add a new *User: E-mail* contextual filter for the view.